# Can Redis Sentinel be used in AKS Kubernetescluster without persistent Volumes?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I have a AKS Cluster and want to deploy Redis with Sentinel, one Master, two Replicas in my Infrastructure Nodepool with three Nodes, one Pod on each (currently doing that via NodeSelector).

I deploy Redis from the Bitnami Helm Chart with a custom values.yaml.

Redis is used purely as in cache Shorttime Key/Value Storage, no really Mission Critical Data is stored but a Redis downtime would still halt the whole Product so we still want the automatic Failover Benefits of Sentinel.

I noticed that while Updating there were Issues with unmounting the persistent Volumes on the old Nodes and mounting them on the new one causing pretty long timeouts and my current Understanding would be that we don't need those Persistent Volumes at all because the necessary Connection Information should be managed by Sentinel on the Replicas so I would just exlude them? Is that possible/advisable?

I found the Post [REDIS cluster without persistence on KUBERNETES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465345/redis-cluster-without-persistence-on-kubernetes) but I believe there a crutual differences between Sentinel and Cluster so I don't feel that answers my Question

Comment: I think it is possible, how do you store Redis configurations? using ConfigMaps or some sort of InitContainers? but generally speaking in my experience Redis Sentinel is useless, as Redis it self is pretty fast and if you want to achieve 99 percent uptime, only a single Redis instance do the work for you and with the help of K8S I think you can even achieve better results.